# Issues when IE browser mode =11 and document mode=7

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I have my application set to document mode=7 through webconfig. When this application is deployed in a windows server 2008 r2, and when i try to access it through internet, the document mode = 7 but my browser mode = 11. Most of the functionalities like sorting of ListView, selected change of checkbox is not working. When i change the browser mode to 7 using IE Explorer, it is functional. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set the X-UA-Compatible META tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

or add a custom header for X-UA-Compatible via IIS, the web.config or in C#:

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE-edge");
```

You can add the custom header in the web.config, see http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders for help.

A word of advice, you need to take the time to upgrade the site to work with modern standards or you are going to lock yourself into a corner. IE 7 is almost a decade old, so consider that.

Comment: The client server is at IE9. So have added 
<httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol> in web.config. It still have issues browsing the url from other versions like IE10, IE11 etc.

Comment: Open the F12 tools. Go to the emulation tab (last one). What is the mode displayed there? Also you might want to download a free virtual machine from http://modern.ie to be completely sure.